# Is it important to study plane algebraic curves before read Fulton's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, algebraic-curves

I'm studying Fulton's [algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and I would like to know how important study plane algebraic geometry before read Fulton's book.

Example of books on this subject:

[Algebraic Curves - Robert J. Walker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387903615)

[Plane Algebraic Curves -  Gerd Fischer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821821229)

I know it's perfectly possible to study Fulton's book without this background, I'm wondering if study algebraic plane curves could help me to have more intuition in some problems algebraic geometry, to sum up, what's the advantages to study the books above before study more advanced subjects.

thanks in advance

Comment: I think Fulton's book is as gentle an introduction to algebraic geometry as any other. I had a cursory glance at the books you mentioned, and they seem to cover the roughly the same topics as Fulton's book. In any case, doesn't Fulton start off with algebraic plane curves too?

Comment: @fixedp yes, but Fulton's book is very dense, many proofs are given as exercises and it doesn't go deeper in the plane algebraic curves subject.

Comment: How deep do you wish to go into algebraic plane curves? In my opinion, the best part of the book are the exercises. They are not terribly difficult (or you were given enough hints to connect the dots), but they usually deal with the most important part of the proof, or give an important example/counter example to the topic at hand. As always though, you may find some examples to practise with online, and it probably helps to find a buddy to work through the book with you or take a relevant course.